# Retrieval of max date group by other column in spark-sql with scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Enviornment - spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7, ScalaLibraryContainer 2.12.3, Scala, SparkSQL, eclipse-jee-oxygen-2-linux-gtk-x86_64

I have a csv file having 3 columns with data-type :String,Long,Date. I want to group by first column which is string and retrieve the maximum date value.

To do this I have created RDD of Person objects from text file and converted it into dataframe 'peopleDF'. Registered the dataframe as a temporary view. I run the following sql statements using the sql methods provided by spark.

```
val maxDateDF = spark.sql("SELECT name, max(birthDate) maxDate FROM people group by name")
```

But it is not giving the correct max date for a name.

My sample data is as follows

```
Michael, 29,01/03/1992
Justin, 19,01/05/2002
Ben Stokes, 29,01/07/1992
Justin, 18,01/08/2003
Ben Stokes, 29,01/07/1993
Ben Stokes, 29,30/06/1993
```

How can I retrieve maximum date value group by other field name?

```
package org.apache.spark.examples.sql

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import java.sql.Date
import breeze.linalg.max

object SparkSQLExample1 {

case class Person(name: String, age: Long, birthDate: String)

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark SQL basic example")
.config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate();
import spark.implicits._
runInferSchemaExample(spark);
spark.stop()
}

 private def runInferSchemaExample(spark: SparkSession): Unit = {
import spark.implicits._
val peopleDF = spark.sparkContext
  .textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt")
  .map(_.split(","))
  .map(attributes => Person(attributes(0), attributes(1).trim.toInt,attributes(2)))
  .toDF()
  
peopleDF.groupBy("age").count().show();
peopleDF.groupBy("name").avg("age").show();
  
 peopleDF.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
 
 implicit val mapEncoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Map[String, Any]]
 val maxDateDF = spark.sql("SELECT name, max(birthDate) maxDate FROM people group by name")
 maxDateDF.map(teenager => teenager.getValuesMap[Any](List("name", "maxDate"))).collect().foreach(println)

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying `max` on a string type column will not give you the maximum date. You need to convert that to a date type column first:

```
val maxDateDF = spark.sql("SELECT name, max(to_date(birthDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy')) maxDate FROM people group by name")
```

If you wish to retain the original date formatting, you can convert it back to a string using `date_format`:

```
val maxDateDF = spark.sql("SELECT name, date_format(max(to_date(birthDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy')), 'dd/MM/yyyy') maxDate FROM people group by name")
```